# Why eclipse doesn't import properly my project?

Tags: android

I have this error:

/._GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.0.jar cannot be read or is not a valid zip file

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path in the error message would be for a file whose name started with a dot (.), and which was located at the root of your filesystem; I bet neither of those things are the case. Perhaps you tried to type "./_GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.0.jar" and reversed the first two character? In any case,  wherever you've specified the path to the jar file, fix it to be the correct path to the correct filename.